# Arcpy Geometry class .ProjectAs function

Tags: python, geometry, arcgis, arcpy

does anyone have experience of using the .ProjectAs `ArcGIS geometry class?` I'm creating a point shapefile. The points are being read from a text file as `WGS1984 lat/long (EPSG 4326)` and I want to project into `OSGB (EPSG: 27700)` and then insert into blank point shapefile using InsertCursor. I can create the point geometry but when inserting the row is doesn't apply the projection to OSGB.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/geometry.htm

```
with open(nmealist,'r') as srcFile:
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutShp, ["SHAPE@", "SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "SHAPE@Z"]) as InsCur:
    for fileLine in srcFile:
        # split the line up into a list
        lSplit = fileLine.split(",")
        if len(lSplit) == 1:
            lSplit = fileLine.split(",")
        if len(lSplit) > 1:
            # more than just one word on the line
            pointsOK = True
            try:
                FILENAME = str(lSplit[0])
                DOS = yymmdd
                TIME = str(lSplit[1])
                EASTING = float(lSplit[3])
                NORTHING = float(lSplit[2])
                HEIGHT = float(lSplit[4])
                HEADING = float(lSplit[5])
                IVA = float(lSplit[6])
                FLIGHTID = sortie

            except:
                arcpy.AddWarning("Unable to translate points")
                pointsOK = False

            if pointsOK:
                newGeom.SpatialReference = srwgs1984 # set spatial reference
                # create a point geometry from the 3 coordinates - EASTING, NORTHING, HEIGHT
                newGeom  = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(EASTING,NORTHING,HEIGHT))
                # project point into OSGB
                projectedpoint = newGeom.projectAs(srosgb)          
                InsCur.insertRow([projectedpoint, EASTING, NORTHING, HEIGHT])# insert this point into the feature class
```

Comment: I think the [gis.se] Stack Exchange is the site to research/ask ArcPy questions on.

Answer (score 0):

In the InsCur.insertRow instruction (last line) your passing the original EASTING, NORTHING, HEIGHT (with no projection) to the new geometry as "SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y", "SHAPE@Z" properties.

Since the point geometry already includes these properties in itself and you already defined the new point geometry correctly with all of these properties, you shouldn't have to set them explicity one by one.

So, try to initiate the InsertCursor with only "SHAPE@" attribute:

```
arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutShp, ["SHAPE@"])
```

and then insert only the projected point object:

```
InsCur.insertRow([projectedpoint])
```